# Pointing Domain A record to EC2 and Serving with HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https

SO I have a domain pointed into a cPanel. Now I wanted my emails to be hosted in cPanel but my website files should serve from AMAZON AWS EC2. So I changed the A record in the cPanel and it works fine. Now I have to make the website serve with HTTPS. Can anyone help me with that ?

I have created a certificate using Amazon certificate manager.

Comment: Uing ALB would be easiest probably.

Comment: Thanks I used Let's Encrypt and certbot and worked as a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a certificate created with ACM on EC2 directly.

Instead, you need to put your instance behind a load balancer (either the ELB classic or the ALB) and then deploy the ACM cert to the load balancer.

You will also need to change the DNS record from an A record point to the IP address to a CNAME that points at the load balancer name.

Another option would be to use Let's Encrypt on the instance to generate the cert.

Your other option would be to purchase a commercial cert & deploy it to the instance.

Comment: Thanks you very much, as per your suggestion I used Let's Encrypt and certbot and it worked as a charm.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Certificate Manger can only be implement with Load Balancer only.
It does not provide you option to download the certificate keys and map with any machine]

TO map your domain with HTTPS you will need to create Elastic Load Balancer CLB/ALB (I would prefer you to create ALB load balancer).

Map your CLB/ALB with ACM for port 443 and add your Instance with create ELB.

FYI: For ALB you will have to create Target group.

Pros: It is cheap and very secure as well, it does provide you TLS Security Policy version.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-policy-table.html

References to Create ACM and Load Balancer:

https://hackernoon.com/getting-a-free-ssl-certificate-on-aws-a-how-to-guide-6ef29e576d22

Comment: Thanks I used Let's Encrypt and certbot and it worked as a charm. Most importantly it's free.